# How to get previous url in Angular 2 with Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to get my previous url

Here is my code

```
prev2() {
    Promise.resolve(this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).
    then(function(v){
      console.log('Previous ' + v);
    })
}
```

But all I get is [Object object]

How could I solve it?

Comment: Try `console.dir(v)` or `console.log('Previous ', v)`

Comment: @ExplosionPills I get AnonymousSubject

Comment: Try `function(v) {v.subscribe(response => console.log(response))}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
prev2() {
this.router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
.subscribe(event => {
  this.current = event.url 
})
}
```